# Оформление прямой речи

Tags: прямая-речь

Помогите, пожалуйста, разрешить непримиримый спор.
 Есть у Розенталя в справочнике вот такое примечание: 
«Если авторские слова, стоящие после прямой речи, представляют собой отдельное предложение, то они начинаются с прописной буквы:
— Скорей, загорелась школа!  — И он побежал по домам будить людей.» 
("Справочник по русскому языку. Пунктуация", 2002. Раздел 14, параграф 47, прим. 2)

Больше ни в одном справочнике такого примечания не попадалось. Но в художественной литературе (как в современных изданиях, так и в изданиях прошлого века) этим правилом активно пользуются. Существует ли оно на самом деле или это яркий пример массового заблуждения?

Answer (score 1):

У Розенталя не может быть заблуждений. ;)
Правило это самоочевидно. Любое законченное предложение начинается с загланой. У Розенталя оно просто сформулировано в явном виде.
А все разговоры про знаки относятся к случаю, когда т.н. авторские слова поясняют прямую речь на предмет кто и как её сказал, т.е. не являются отдельным законченным предложением.